# Java Servlet is there a way to grab the .outerhtml of your printwriter

Tags: java, html, xml, servlets

I'm new to servlets and I'm having trouble grabbing the html elements and tags. basically is there something that goes along.

```
`PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 out.println(xmlcombo);
 String x = out.outerhtml();
 //put x in a file for user to download
`
```

I know this may seem a bit unnecessary, but my xmlcombo is an xml string that "appears" like html with xsl. It would be too difficult to simulate a **rightclick->grab source** and obtain the html that way

Comment: What would outerhtml() do??? All you've done to variable out, is feed it your variable xmlcombo. All it could possibly give you back, is the variable xmlcombo you just gave it and you still have right there. x and xmlcombo would therefore contain the same thing, and you never needed to call outerhtml().

Comment: Sorry, my understanding is that my xml document in the presence of my xsl file is html in firefox(rightclick->view source->html). I don't want the xml but rather the html

Comment: From what you're describing, it looks like the xml to html conversion is done by Firefox, not by your java website.

Comment: @kumesana Maybe that is happening. If that happens is there a way to grab the html that firefox is converting it to?

Comment: I've been looking for such a tool myself. The best I could find was right click->inspect element and use the DOM tree in place of an actual HTML source.